# python lstm layer variable input length

Tags: python, keras, lstm, speech-recognition, sentiment-analysis

i am working on speech emotion recognition i have files of different lengths i extracting mel spectrogram as my x variables as you know mel specgrogram change according to file length

```
model = Sequential()
    model.add(layers.LSTM(100, input_shape=(None,1)))

    model.add(Conv1D(256, 8, padding='same', activation="relu"))

    model.add(Conv1D(256, 8, padding='same', activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(8)))

    model.add(Conv1D(128, 8, padding='same', activation="relu"))

    model.add(Conv1D(128, 8, padding='same', activation="relu"))

    model.add(Conv1D(128, 8, padding='same', activation="relu"))

    model.add(Conv1D(128, 8, padding='same', activation="relu"))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(8)))

    model.add(Conv1D(64, 8, padding='same', activation="relu"))

    model.add(Conv1D(64, 8, padding='same', activation="relu"))

    #model.add(Flatten())

    model.add(bidirectionnel(layers.LSTM(256)))

    model.add(Dense(256, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))

    model.add(Dense(2)) 
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))


    model.compile(optimizer="Adam",
              loss="binary_crossentropy",
              metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

but i keep getting this error

**Input 0 of layer conv1d_3 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 100)**
it works with replacing the firrst lstm layer with a cnn layer with fixed inputs but i want to have a flexible input layer for inference i know that 0 padding is a solution but during inference i cannot define the max length of my audio

Answer (score 0):

LSTMs, or RNNs in general, are fundamentally incapable of dealing with varying length of input. It is one of the motivations behind transformer architectures (as you might have noticed by adding CNN in front).

You probably want to do padding or apply transformer-like architecture.